# How to call IHost's Run() in a headed UWP IoT Core app

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-10-iot-core

What is the correct way to run `IHost` in a headed UWP App?

*Update: This is avoid issues with running code on the UI thread.*

I have to have something working for today so for now I went for `Thread.Start`.

```
internal sealed partial class App : Windows.UI.Xaml.Application
{
    (...)
    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        (...)
        new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;
            MyRun();
        }).Start();
    }

    public void MyRun()
    {
        (...) 
        Host = ConfigureHost().Build();
        Host.Run();
    }

    private IHostBuilder ConfigureHost()
    {
        return new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureHostConfiguration...
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration...
    }
}
```

Is this a correct way? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, we can not host a web server with HostBuilder in UWP. But you can host a web server via StreamSocketListener. You can refer to this blog [here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/09/06/windows-10-iot-core-blockly/?#vh7Xz3fOA9PZTYyu.97). Or you can separate the web server from the UWP.

Comment: We're not hosting a web server. We're using HostBuilder to create long running services and for dependency injection.

Comment: It seems that UWP does not support HostBuilder. I can not find any document or article about this issue.